# Postgres saves 'timestamp with time zone' with default time zone

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in Postgres (13.3):

```
create table owner (date_time timestamp with time zone);
```

I've saved a record with time zone:

```
insert into owner(date_time) values (timestamp with time zone '2010-10-10 10:10:10.000000 +03:00');
```

I expect that the value is saved with timezone I defined, but the actual value is:

`2010-10-10 07:10:10.000000 +00:00`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name [timestamp with time zone](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) is perhaps unfortunate, but it's been that way for decades and we are stuck with it now.

It might better be named `absolute timestamp` and what it actually *stores* is a timestamp in UTC. What it actually *displays* is a timestamp in your client's defined timezone.

```
richard=> SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
┌───────────────────────────────┐
│       current_timestamp       │
├───────────────────────────────┤
│ 2022-11-22 14:03:57.919421+00 │
└───────────────────────────────┘
(1 row)

richard=> SET timezone = 'Europe/Paris';
SET
richard=> SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
┌───────────────────────────────┐
│       current_timestamp       │
├───────────────────────────────┤
│ 2022-11-22 15:04:10.943315+01 │
└───────────────────────────────┘
(1 row)
```

If you actually want to maintain the timezone offset you will either need to separately store the offset time, or the zone name (e.g. "Europe/Paris").

Note that they are NOT the same in zones which have DST.